# Plotting entries of one table vs entries of another with a condition on a third table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have three Tables, say, `A={1,2,3,4,5}`, `B={1,2,3,4,5}`, `C={1.1,2.2,17,1.5,5}` of the same length. I'd like to plot (using `ListPlot`) entries of table `A` vs the corresponding entries of table `B` if the corresponding entries of `C` lie between, say, 1 and 3.

That is, the list of points to plot is `{{1,1},{2,2},{4,4}}`.

How do I do that?

As a next step, I'd like to produce multiple plots (on one diagram) of entries of `A` vs entries of `B` for various conditions on `C`.

Comment: Something like `Pick[Transpose[{A, B}], Thread[1 <= C <= 3]] // ListPlot` would work, I guess.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis, Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear. May I suggest answering your own question, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Position` first to find the index, then use `Extract`

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
c = {1.1, 2.2, 17, 1.5, 5};
idx = Position[c, x_ /; 1 < x < 3];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Extract[a, idx], Extract[b, idx]}], Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Based on Guesswhoitis's comment, the solution is to use `Pick` with `Thread`:

`Pick[Transpose[{A, B}], Thread[1 <= C <= 3]] // ListPlot`

`ListPlot` also allows to plot several plots  using

`ListPlot[{list1,list2,...}]`

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to plot A and B over several conditions derived from C, it would probably be worth writing a function that not only takes A, B, and C, but also a list of the conditions expressed as pure functions and does the selection for every function on the list. This is not a very difficult extension of what you already have.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
c = {1.1, 2.2, 17, 1.5, 5};
f = {1 <= # <= 3 &, # > 2. &};

pickByC[a_, b_, c_, funcs_] :=
  Pick[Transpose[{a, b}], #] & /@ Table[f /@ c, {f, funcs}]

ListPlot[pickByC[a, b, c, f],
  PlotMarkers -> 
    {Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled@.03]}], 
     Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled@.017]}]}]
```

[image: plot]

Note: because the points from the two sets plotted were both selected from the same underlying data, I took some care to make sure that when one data point was selected twice, the duplication was visible in the plot. If there were a large number of criteria functions, the visibility of multiples could become an significant issue.

#### Update

As Guess who it is. points out in his comment

```
pickByC[a_, b_, c_, funcs_] := Table[Pick[Transpose[{a, b}], f /@ c], {f, funcs}]
```

is a better formulation.

Comment: Why `Map[]` twice? `Table[Pick[Transpose[{a, b}], f /@ c], {f, funcs}]`. But if you must, `Pick[Transpose[{a, b}], # /@ c] & /@ funcs`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. My only excuse is that I was very tired when I wrote this answer.